# How to check when a point is rendered on canvas js dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts

I'm using a dynamic line chart from Canvas.js to render an ECG (heart beat) signal and I also came up with a peak detection algorithm but I need to know when exactly a peak is rendered so I can trigger a beeping sound. Sets of points are inserted in the chart's points array as they come through a websocket so I have no control over single points rendering.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Interesting project! I don't use Canvas.js, but a quick look at their docs indicates there's no API hook to listen for `data-has-changed` events. You will probably have to listen for websocket message events and analyze each new incoming point-set for peaks.

Comment: Well that's some bad news as I'm too deep into it to switch libraries with a deadline on Tuesday... Listening for websocket messages is trivial but I doubt the moment a message that contains a peak arrives will coincide with the actual moment the peak shows up on the chart. I'll try it out anyway but I'll probably end up with unsync'd beeping all over the place...

Comment: Ok, as a workaround, how about checking for peaks in the new dataset (and beeping if yes) just before you do `theChart.render`.  Test to see if the beep sounds close enough to the redrawn chart.

Comment: @markE I eventually tried to do that but the result was as expected so eventually dropped this feature due to deadline pressure. I'll dig around for a solution if there's still time. Thanks for your answers anyway!